# About Invariant Factors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A$ is a $2\times2$ matrix with minimal polynomial $x^2- 5x+4$, $B$ is a $2\times2$ matrix with minimal polynomial $x^2 -6x +8$, and let $O$ be the $2\times2$ matrix with all entries $0$.

Find the invariant factors of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}A & O \\ O & B \end{pmatrix}$.

I thought the characteristic polynomial is $(x-1)(x-2)(x-4)^2$， then I get stuck...

Comment: Thank you for explaining your thoughts; in addition to showing you have at least tried the problem, it will help people give more useful answers to you as well.

Comment: Do you know the definition of "invariant factors" of a square matrix with coefficients in a field?